# How to solve the problem "package is broken or not fully installed"?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, mysql

I am new in using Linux and I just installed a package name `openimscore-fhoss` and then during the installation they asked me to put the password for the SQL database but I made a mistake when enter without the password and then the installation was broken. I got the error:

```
SQL Data
Starting MySQL...
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ] 
 -->Some data will be inserted in MySQL database.hss database configuration
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
dpkg: error processing package openimscore-fhoss (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openimscore-fhoss
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to reconfigure the installation by using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openimscore-fhoss` but it showed the error:

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: openimscore-fhoss is broken or not fully installed
```

I also tried to remove/uninstall the package and then install again but I still got the errors related to the SQL. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you log in as user `root` on your local MySQL server? See the question [Can't log into MySQL](/q/120718/175814) for instructions how to do that and restart the service and/or reset the password, if you can't log in. Once you can log in, you can try to finish the installation of `openimscore-fhoss` with `sudo apt-get install -f openimscore-fhos`. Please report back with how it went.

Comment: Hi David, yes I can login to my local MySQL server and when I try `sudo apt-get install -f openimscore-fhoss`, I still get error: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
dpkg: error processing package openimscore-fhoss (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openimscore-fhoss
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Ok, then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Hi, I already tried it but I still get error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) dpkg: error processing package openimscore-fhoss (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: openimscore-fhoss E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Duong: David Foerster above asked you can you log as **root** to your MySQL server, not as an ordinary user. Give user **root** privileges to access your database.

Comment: I use the command `mysql -u root -p` to access to my  SQL, is it right?

Comment: @Duong: I is right... Almost. You use `-p`, which means logging in requires a password. I guess installation process knows nothing about your password and that's why it fails. Try removing your password for a while, after install you can set it again.